# Aggregation, Firebase java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to collect the seconds data I get with Firebase and will show it in hours / minutes.
How can i do that?

Here is my code;:

```
private void lastData() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        startData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("myseconds")
                .child(TrackKeyMY);
        PeriodHow = startData.orderByChild("Date").equalTo(String.valueOf(currentDateandTime));
        PeriodHow.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (data.child("Date").exists()) {
                        kackere = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        whatlogin.setText(Integer.toString(kackere) + " Login");

                        Number seconds = data.getValue(OnlinePeriod.class).getDuration().getSeconds();
                        Log.d("TAG", "My Seconds Data " + seconds);
                    } else {
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
```

This my logchat;

```
2021-02-28 22:40:54.164 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 32
2021-02-28 22:40:54.165 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 26
2021-02-28 22:40:54.166 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 40
2021-02-28 22:40:54.167 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 19
2021-02-28 22:40:54.168 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 26
2021-02-28 22:40:54.168 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 21
2021-02-28 22:40:54.168 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 13
2021-02-28 22:40:54.170 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 38
2021-02-28 22:40:54.170 26049-26049/com.androremtest D/TAG: My Seconds Data 18
```

The result I want to get; 3 Minutes 53 Seconds

Comment: You will have to create a class variable for example, that keeps track of your seconds + seconds, everytime your OnDataChange is called>

Then at some point later on, you can convert those seconds to minutes.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

create a static variable for example

```
  static long aggregator=0;
```

then each time you get the seconds from the datasnapshot add the seconds you got to this variable

```
  long seconds = data.getValue(OnlinePeriod.class).getDuration().getSeconds();
  aggregator+=seconds;
  Log.d("TAG", "My Seconds Data " + seconds);
```

now you will have your time aggregating in this variable and once you want to show it just divide by 60 to show it in minutes
float minutes= aggregator/60;
Log.d("TAG", "My minutes Data " + minutes);

Comment: This is a really cool method. But I can't run the code https://prnt.sc/109n4ib

Comment: for aggregator/60 try to do the operation separately and save the result in a float variable since the result is decimal number

Comment: I changed the value to float, but I get the same error with + =.

Comment: Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Float', 'java.lang.Number'

Comment: make both variables float or both number you are trying to add a float to a number

Comment: Nothing has changed. Maybe I could be wrong. Please write down how to use the code?
I'm not very good at this
Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Float', 'java.lang.Float'

Comment: try aggregator=aggregator+seconds

Comment: I tried this. I get the same error
Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Number', 'java.lang.Number
'

Comment: may i ask why are you using the Number class ? if its not necessary to your program change it to primitives' type such as int , long since you can't perform all arithmetic operations on Number

Comment: I edited the two data as Integer and it worked but it did not give the result I wanted. I don't know what that means.


`D/TAG: My minutes Data 0`
`D/TAG: My minutes Data 1`
`My minutes Data 1`
`My minutes Data 2`
`My minutes Data 2`
`My minutes Data 3`
`My minutes Data 4`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from @Susan Mustafa, you need to sum up all of them and then change to minute.

```
long totalSeconds = 0;
for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (data.child("Date").exists()) {
        kackere = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        whatlogin.setText(Integer.toString(kackere) + " Login");

        Number seconds = data.getValue(OnlinePeriod.class).getDuration().getSeconds();
        totalSeconds += seconds.longValue();
        Log.d("TAG", "My Seconds Data " + seconds);
   }
}
Log.d("TAG", "Total seconds: " + totalSeconds);
Log.d("TAG", "Total min: " + (totalSeconds/60));
```